# permission denied error on initdb when installing alfresco community edition

Tags: linux, postgresql, permissions, alfresco, alfresco-share

I previously had installed alfresco community edition using the installer, but my server eventually ran out of hard drive space and things go corrupted.  I wasn't able to run the uninstaller (getting strange permissions issues).

So i removed the entire installation folder and am trying to install again.  It gives me this error when I'm running the installer as root:
bash: /opt/alfresco-community/postgresql/bin/initdb: Permission denied

When I look for the folder /opt/alfresco-community/postgresql, it doesn't exist.  Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Did you check to make sure that both tomcat and postgres were completely shut down before removing the installation directory? Do a pas -ef|grep tomcat and ps -ef|grep postgres to find out.

Answer (score 0):

You run into multiple problems if you install alfresco as a root user. Because it tends to make many things in accessible for normal user and Alfresco expect to have access on those items for user called "alfresco". That create issues.